# Como ler esse JSON corretamente? MSSQL e Node

Tags: javascript, json, sql-server, node.js

```
{
  "recordsets": [
    [
      {
        "IdUsuario": 5152490,
        "strNome": "Roberto ",
        "IdPapel": 1
      },
      {
        "IdUsuario": 5152490,
        "strNome": "Roberto ",
        "IdPapel": 3000001
      }
    ]
  ]
```

Estou tentando devolver para o cliente apenas as permissões dele (IdPapel), porém, não estou conseguindo.

Segue o código que executa a query e traz como resultado o JSON apresentado:

```
function verify(query, res, user) {
  sql.connect(dbConfig, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err);
      res.sendStatus(403);
      sql.close();
    } else {
      var request = new sql.Request();
      request.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
          res.sendStatus(403);
          sql.close();
        } else {
          res.send(result);
          sql.close();
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Alguma dica?

Obrigado!

Comment: Você quer enviar um array contendo cada IdPapel é isso?

Comment: Na verdade quero enviar um JSON para o outro lado, contendo apenas os papéis.

Comment: Certo, então no caso você quer mandar aquele array de usuários ali?

Comment: Gostaria de enviar o nome e todos os papéis desse usuário. Esse json do exemplo apresenta o mesmo usuário várias vezes, porém, alterando apenas o IdPapel. Mas se eu souber como envio apenas o IdPapel, consigo enviar o nome. Acontece que não consigo pegar um elemento especifico do array, da erro.

Comment: Saquei o que você quer. Esse JSON é o que tá salvo na variável result ali da query do SQL correto?

Comment: Isso mesmo @JoãoPedroHenrique . Estou pegando esse json a partir do mssql pelo node.

Comment: Ok, vou escrever uma resposta então

Comment: Só mais uma pergunta, ele tá voltando o JSON já decodificado, correto?

Comment: Ele ta voltando o JSON da mesma maneira que coloquei no exemplo. Ao requisitar pela API, traz esse JSON

Comment: saquei. Mas essa função que faz a chamada no banco de dados... A variável result é uma string com um JSON ou ele já decodificou o JSON?

Comment: Eu não sei dizer... Inclusive acredito que pode ser por isso que não estou conseguindo extrair o que eu quero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ter um array em que cada elemento seja um `IdPapel`, você precisa acessar o array de usuários retornado pela consulta ao Banco de Dados. Supondo que a resposta esteja armazenada na variável `result`, podemos fazer:

```
const respostaDecodificada = result
// Aqui estamos pegando o array com os usuários
const arrayUsuarios = respostaDecodificada.recordsets[0]
// Aqui estamos criando um novo array, com o IdPapel de cada usuário
const arrayIdPapel = arrayUsuarios.map(usuario => usuario.IdPapel)
```

E após a execução do código, se dermos um `console.log(arrayIdPapel)` receberemos: `[ 1, 3000001 ]`. Pelo que você comentou é isso que você queria. Depois basta fazer `res.send(arrayIdPapel)`.

Comment: O arrayUsuarios deve ser igual a respostaDecodificada[0], certo?

Comment: Na realidade, `const arrayUsuarios = respostaDecodificada.recordsets[0]`. Vou corrigir na resposta ;)

Comment: Tentei o que você propôs e é retornado erro no retorno da API :(

Comment: O que aparece? O erro é no cliente ou no servidor?

Comment: No postman aparece mensagem de erro e no log do servidor, essa mensagem: *59553 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream. Se eu apagar tudo e deixar o res.send(result), funciona normalmente, porém, com a mensagem toda.

Comment: O problema não está na resposta. Aparentemente, você na realidade não está conseguindo se conectar ao seu banco de dados

Comment: Tenho certeza que não é isso, até porque se eu alterar para res.send(result), eu obtenho o resultado no lado do cliente normalmente

Comment: Estranho... De repente ele já tá vindo o JSON decodificado... tenta colocar `const respostaDecodificada = result` ao invés do que tem agora...

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Muito obrigado pela ajuda @João Pedro Henrique, funcionou! Se puder editar a resposta para que eu de como certa

Comment: Farei isso agora. Fico feliz que deu certo :D

Comment: resposta editada